# Why my IoU keep decrease in training with tensorflow / keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm training an U-net like model for semantic segmentation but the IoU keep decrease epochs after epochs.
This is my IoU and IoU loss function. My input and output mask is an numpy array with `dtype=np.bool` so I casted it to float32 for calculate the IoU.
I don't know what is the problem? My metrics function or my model. I really need someone help me on this.

```
def iou(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.keras.backend.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred = tf.keras.backend.flatten(y_pred)
    y_true_f = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    y_pred_f = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)
    intersection = tf.keras.backend.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    union = tf.keras.backend.sum(y_true_f) + tf.keras.backend.sum(y_pred_f) - intersection
    return (intersection + 1e-7) / (union + 1e-7)

def iou_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1.0 - iou(y_true, y_pred)

# Compile model
metrics = [iou_loss, iou, 'accuracy']
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate), loss=iou, metrics=[metrics], run_eagerly=True)
```

This is my training results

```
Epoch 2/100
34/34 [==============================] - 3s 89ms/step - loss: 0.0186 - iou_loss: 0.9814 - iou: 0.0186 - accuracy: 0.9022 - val_loss: 0.0358 - val_iou_loss: 0.9647 - val_iou: 0.0353 - val_accuracy: 0.9460

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.03619 to 0.03579, saving model to /content/gdrive/MyDrive/model_ccnet_iris.h5
Epoch 3/100
34/34 [==============================] - 3s 89ms/step - loss: 0.0158 - iou_loss: 0.9843 - iou: 0.0157 - accuracy: 0.8972 - val_loss: 0.0352 - val_iou_loss: 0.9652 - val_iou: 0.0348 - val_accuracy: 0.9071

Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 0.03579 to 0.03525, saving model to /content/gdrive/MyDrive/model_ccnet_iris.h5
Epoch 4/100
34/34 [==============================] - 3s 88ms/step - loss: 0.0132 - iou_loss: 0.9868 - iou: 0.0132 - accuracy: 0.8910 - val_loss: 0.0348 - val_iou_loss: 0.9656 - val_iou: 0.0344 - val_accuracy: 0.8690

Epoch 00004: val_loss improved from 0.03525 to 0.03485, saving model to /content/gdrive/MyDrive/model_ccnet_iris.h5
Epoch 5/100
34/34 [==============================] - 3s 87ms/step - loss: 0.0112 - iou_loss: 0.9888 - iou: 0.0112 - accuracy: 0.8842 - val_loss: 0.0345 - val_iou_loss: 0.9659 - val_iou: 0.0341 - val_accuracy: 0.8411

Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 0.03485 to 0.03455, saving model to /content/gdrive/MyDrive/model_ccnet_iris.h5
Epoch 6/100
34/34 [==============================] - 3s 85ms/step - loss: 0.0096 - iou_loss: 0.9904 - iou: 0.0096 - accuracy: 0.8740 - val_loss: 0.0343 - val_iou_loss: 0.9662 - val_iou: 0.0338 - val_accuracy: 0.8216
```

Answer (score 0):

The function of an optimizer is to minimize the loss function
You set `IoU` as the loss function, that is why it is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

The second function `iou_loss` should be used as the loss instead of the `iou` function.

Comment: Can you explain a bit?